# php mysql .htaccess errors

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

I am creating a profile page for users using PHP, MySQL, and `.htaccess` (this is my first time using `.htaccess` files).

Yesterday it worked perfectly and I was able to make the URL like this `(http://localhost/Unnamed site 2/resources/*username*)` but today I can do it and the browser gives me the following error message:

> **Internal Server Error**
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request. Please contact the server
>   administrator, admin@localhost and inform them of the time the error
>   occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the
>   error. More information about this error may be available in the
>   server error log.

How can I resolve this?  Here is the relevant code:

**profile.php**

```
if (isset($_GET['u'])) {
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['u']);

    if (ctype_alnum($username)) {
        // Check that the user exists
        $check = mysql_query("SELECT user_name, first_name FROM user WHERE user_name = '$username' ")or die(mysql_error());
        if (mysql_num_rows($check) == 1) {
            $get = mysql_fetch_assoc($check);
            $username = $get['user_name'];
            $fname = $get['first_name'];
        } else {
            // this line is to redirect the non-existent users to the index.php
            echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; url=http://localhost/Unnamed Site 2/resources/index.php\">";
            exit();  
        }
    }
}

// echo "$username";
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?u=$1
```

Comment: "More information about this error may be available in the server error log." -- what's in the error log? :)

Comment: did you try `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?u=$1 [L]`? so that the server does not do the rewrite on and on in an endlessloop?

Comment: sir i am new to the htaccess file and i do not know how to fix and waht to try can you explain to me more ?

Comment: @ jpatiaga  where is the error log file in the localhost ??

Comment: @user2172837 simply replace the line `RewriteRule` in your code to the one that ITroubs provided :)

Comment: BTW I like title of your question :)

Comment: And, as server suggested - please check log files created by apache and post here. There we can find some interesting info...

Comment: i did as ITroubs say but still the same problem and the same error msg

Comment: @user2172837: Do you not know how to access your error logs? We need to see more information that Apache is providing so that we can help.

Comment: @  Mike Anthony :  i asked my question again if you can take a look and help me i will appreciate that  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15487371/php-mysql-htaccess-used-for-the-first-time]